# Filtering file entries based on another file as match condition

Tags: bash, file, filtering, editing

Really beginner of bash and scripting so sorry if it is very basic question to You.

I have file1 with ~1 million rows contain two fields in every row.
I have file2 with ~270.000 rows, single entry in every rows. It is common with file1 field 1.

The goal is to have a filtered list from the file1 (keep the filed1 and field2 entries) based on file2 entries.

Example:

`file1`

```
1 A

2 B

3 C

4 C

5 D

6 A

7 G

8 K

122 F

.

.

56677 A

.

7272727272 A

1.000.000 A

File2:

1

2

3

9

122

56677

7272727272
```

I want filter the first column based on file2 and output should be like this:

```
1 A

2 B

3 C

122 F

56677 A

7272727272 A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line, if it gave expected output:

```
grep -Fwf file2 file1
```

or

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}a[$1]' file2 file1
```

Comment: I tested it and first option gave me ~50k result - I estimated the same number of result as many rows in file2. Second option empty results. I forget to mention that the order of the common column (first field) is different. Can it influence the result? We 100% sure that file2 entries are in file. Thanks Krisztian

Comment: @farkask Remove `-w`?

Comment: @BroSlow: Same result and looks both option works fine but our raw data corrupted I think.